# Using KendoUI DetailTemplate- How do I use literal for AJAX results

Tags: kendo-ui

Using the DetailTemplate grid example for KendoUI as my basepoint
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/detailtemplate.html

I am trying to add a HREF link to the Orders tab that would open up another page.

I have tried using the #= OrderId # notation, but this seems to only access the first AJAX call result set - that is the data returned pulling back the users information.

I want to be able to access the information pulled back for the orders - see code snippet below
I have tried using the ClientTemplate method but to no avail, as it can't access (or it doesn't exist) the #= OrderId # literal.

I am using AJAX to pull the info for both sets of data, so don't seem able to use the Template method.

Any advice on accessing this level of JSON data returned as a secondary call would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script id="employeesTemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
            .Name("TabStrip_#=EmployeeID#")
            .SelectedIndex(0)
            .Items(items =>
            {
                items.Add().Text("Orders").Content(@<text>
                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.OrderViewModel>()
                        .Name("Orders_#=EmployeeID#")
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Width(101);
                            columns.Bound(o => o.ShipCountry).Width(140);
                            columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress).Width(200);
                            columns.Bound(o => o.ShipName).Width(200);

Thanks in advance
Andrew
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.ClientTemplate("\\#:OrderId  \\#");
```

Notice double back slashes.